# Operator symbol for iterator - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was having a look at the `Iterable` interface in Kotlin (package `kotlin.collections`) and noticed that it has one function – the `iterator` function which returns an `Iterator`. However, I also noticed that it has the `operator` keyword.

As far as I understand from the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) (correct me if I'm wrong) the `operator` keyword is used for syntactic sugar e.g. `operator fun` of `a.plus(b)` enables us to write `a + b` instead of writing `a.plus(b)`.

So, I was wondering, what is the "syntactic shortcut" if it exists for the `iterator()` function? Or is there another purpose for the keyword `operator` I'm unaware of? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: Perhaps it's the usage of in when looping? for (i in <Iterable instance) {}? But, If we look at the Iterator interface, we can add the operator keyword to hasNext() and next(). I feel like I'm missing out on a fundamental aspect of the operator keyword usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `for`-loops](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops) (not the [docs for operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) you might have looked at) provides the answer:

> As mentioned before, for iterates through anything that provides an iterator. This means that it:
>
> - has a member or an extension function `iterator()` that returns `Iterator<>`:
>
>   - has a member or an extension function `next()`
>   - has a member or an extension function `hasNext()` that returns Boolean.
>
> **All of these three functions need to be marked as `operator`.**

The `for`-loop requires the `iterator()`, `next()` and `hasNext()` methods to be marked with `operator`. This is another use of the `operator` keyword besides overloading operators.

For JVM interobility, Java classes implementing `java.util.Iterable` don't need the `operator` keyword on the `iterator()` method because it doesn't exist in Java (and this makes it possible to iterate over Java `Iterable`s from Kotlin code).

Comment: Yikes, you beat my comment by 40 or so seconds. I'm not quite sure 'need' is the correct word as if you implement your own class, it's not necessary to add the operator keyword. Is that because it's implicit through the override keyword?

Comment: You can think of `java.lang.Iterable.iterate` as already having the `operator` keyword (and it is inherited). From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html): _When overriding your operator overloads, you can omit `operator`_

Comment: Mmmm. The point of the `operator` usage is to allow you to iterate through objects which _don't_ implement `Iterable`, as long as they have the necessary methods — even if they're only extension methods.  So you're not tied to the object hierarchy the way you are in Java.